# Full nodes for ETH, BTC, and USDT in one server

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, tether

I want to build a blockchain wallet that works with BTC, ETH, and USDT, I understand that I must to run a server for bitcoin (**bitcoin core**) and ethereum (**Ethereum Node**) full nodes.

I have 2 questions now:

1- Has any full node for **Tether**?

2- Has it any benefit or danger that I will run 3 full nodes in **one** server?

Comment: Your understanding is quite much incorrect. It does not make sense to answer this question, as the assumptions are so much off. I suggest you start by reversing engineering some existing wallet.

Comment: Yes, I know it, I'm trying to lunch full nodes with docker and Kubernetes in one server but separated logically, this [link](https://medium.com/mwpartners/containerizing-bitcoin-and-ethereum-with-docker-7c447b484f3a) help me too much.

Comment: I suggest you first study how cryptocurrencies and existing wallets work before trying to build your own. First learn to walk before you can run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to run another node for Tether you just need to connect to ETH and pass it's smart contract data from ethereum blockchain!
which you can see the smart contract [here](https://ethplorer.io/address/0x6c9e3e437b0f06c5366fae4ea4e6cd6fb1803bdf)

Try Web3.js and Infura{it has free trial} and use testnet to experiment everything

**about security**
the only thing that you should keep safe, is the private keys and backup mnemonics